# How to load 4 differents pages (containing d3js graph) in 4 div on a same page in jQuery / JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried almost everything but I can't find a way to make it work correly.

## What do I have?

- 1 index page with a `table` and 4 `div` (which are not displayed) ;
- 4 html page with some content (graphs).

## What do I want ?

Each div contains 1 of the corresponding html file.
When I click on the table (one of the "title"), the `div` is displayed

## What is the result ?

Well basically, all html pages are loaded in the same `div`. The 3 others are blank...[Graphs on each other in the same div even if not called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xxDm.jpg).

## what it strange ?

When I load "ordinary" page (no graph d3js), it works perfectly...
I guess it has to be a problem in loading the graph
Thank you for your help :)

Here is the code:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <table width="70%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>Sample id</th>
                <th @click='gcmodal = !gcmodal'>GC Dropout</th>
                <th @click='atmodal = !atmodal'>AT Dropout</th>
                <th @click='dupmodal = !dupmodal'>% Duplicates</th>
                <th @click='offmodal = !offmodal'>% Off target</th>
                <th @click='trcmodal = !trcmodal'>Total Read Count</th>
            </tr>   
        </table>

        <div id='gc' v-show='gcmodal'></div>
        <div id='at' v-show='atmodal'></div>
        <div id='dup' v-show='dupmodal'></div>
        <div id='off' v-show='offmodal'></div>
        <div id='trc' v-show='trcmodal'></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>


    new Vue({
    el: "#app",
        data: {
            gcmodal:false,
            atmodal:false,
            dupmodal:false,
            offmodal:false,
            trcmodal:false,
        }
    })

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#gc').load('./gc_dropout.html'),
        $('#at').load('./at_dropout.html'),
        $('#dup').load('./duplicates.html'),
        $('#off').load('./off_target.html'),
        $('#trc').load('./total_read_count.html')
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't have a solution right now but I think you could take advantage of vue components rather than mixing vue and jquery. This may help you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML ***[iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)*** element.

its main attributes are:-

**width** *(the width of the embedded page*)

**height** *(the height of the embedded page)*

**title** *(the title of the embedded page)*

**src** *(the link of the page you want to embed)*

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <table width="70%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>Sample id</th>
        <th @click='gcmodal = !gcmodal'>GC Dropout</th>
        <th @click='atmodal = !atmodal'>AT Dropout</th>
        <th @click='dupmodal = !dupmodal'>% Duplicates</th>
        <th @click='offmodal = !offmodal'>% Off target</th>
        <th @click='trcmodal = !trcmodal'>Total Read Count</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id='gc' v-show='gcmodal'>
      <iframe id="gcTable" width="300" height="300" title="gc dropout" src="./gc_dropout.html" />
    </div>
    <div id='at' v-show='atmodal'>
      <iframe id="atTable" width="300" height="300" title="at dropout" src="./at_dropout.html" />
    </div>
    <div id='dup' v-show='dupmodal'>
      <iframe id="duplicatesTable" width="300" height="300" title="duplicates" src="./duplicates.html" />
    </div>
    <div id='off' v-show='offmodal'>
      <iframe id="offTable" width="300" height="300" title="off target" src="./off_target.html" />
    </div>
    <div id='trc' v-show='trcmodal'>
    <iframe id="trcTable" width="300" height="300" title="total read count" src="./total_read_count.html" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      gcmodal: false,
      atmodal: false,
      dupmodal: false,
      offmodal: false,
      trcmodal: false,
    }
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: No Problem. Please mark it as correct if it helped you.